# Handling object between classes

Tags: java, object, interface

I am working with a properties object and I need to use it in a few different classes, the same instant of it. I could just pass it between them I suppose but I feel like that could get out of hand pretty quickly. Is the solution to my problem an interface?

Because I have this method where I load in the properties to the properties object:

```
public void loadFile(String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException{

        if(!filepath.contains(".properties")){
            System.out.println("Not a properties file.");
            return;
        }
        try{
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(filepath));            
        } catch(IOException e){
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File '" + filepath
                    + "' not found.");
        }

        setProperties();
        System.out.println(this.getFtpHost());
    }
```

and in `setProperties()` I just set everything, like `ftpHost = prop.getProperty("ftp.host")`. Aside from getters for all of the properties I set that's all this class is used for (creating the object).

I guess if the solution is an interface could someone explain how I'd put some of this stuff into one conceptually?

Comment: have you thought of using a utility class? like a static class? That might be another way to do it

Comment: Agree with Abdul -- `java.lang.System.getProperties()` and such sounds like a good model for this.

Comment: Mind giving me the 30 second shpeal? The only reason im doing it this way is because the app is running from an executable jar and the file path is passed in as args[0] then I am calling this class to pull the info from that file path. So the info once it is in the app is static, but it could be different depending on which file you select to import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Singleton pattern is what you should use.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Keep in mind that SO is not a forum with conversation threads, it is a question-answer site. And as such, answers should be well thought and well fleshed out. If you want to suggest a Singleton pattern for the OPs case, it would be better to demonstrate how the OP could incorporate that pattern into their scenario.

Comment: Despite the lack of help/guidance. I chose to go this route after some research. So you win i suppose :p

Answer (score 1):

You can make class like this and put all properties in it.

```
class PropertiesObject {

   private PropertiesObject instance = null;

   public static PropertiesObject instace() {
       if(instance == null) {
           loadInstance(); // this is done one time
       }
       return instance;
   }
}
```